# Visual Studio Code split terminal on startup with different name and color

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, customization

I want to vscode to open split terminal by default in which one should be named "server" and color "red" where the second one should be named "git" and colored "green". note that default terminal is git bash.

I have created this task in tasks.json file in .vscode folder

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run 2 Terminals",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn": [
                "terminal1"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "terminal1",
            "command": "${command:multiCommand.startFirstTerminal}"
        },
    ]
}
```

and this is my setting's json

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "terminal.integrated.windowsEnableConpty": false,
    "terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell": true,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
    "multiCommand.commands": [
        {
            "command": "multiCommand.startFirstTerminal",
            "sequence": [
                "workbench.action.terminal.newInActiveWorkspace",
                {
                    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.renameWithArg",
                    "args": {
                        "name": "Server",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.changeColorWithArgs",
                    "args": {
                        "text": "${terminal.ansiRed}"
                    }
                },
                "workbench.action.terminal.split",
                {
                    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.renameWithArg",
                    "args": {
                        "name": "Git"
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

and I have installed one extension called[multicommand](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

but i still don't know how to give each terminal different color and icons like this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwakH.png)